# XAMPP, auto redirection of path from localhost:81 to localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, netbeans, xampp

I am new to netbeans and wordpress development, Currently developing a wordpress site in the local environment. I use XAMPP, where my default path is localhost:81.

http://localhost:81/phpmyadmin & http://localhost:81/dashboard/ works totally fine along with couple of other sample web projects (not wordpress based).

The problem is when I run the wordpress site the through Netbeans, for couple of seconds the correct URL http://localhost:81/projectname/index.php is shown, but then it redirects to http://localhost/projectname/ (shows error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED). This issue is the same for both Chrome and Firefox browser.

Any help would be much appreciated. TIA

Comment: change the port in Netbeans

Comment: Thank you for your answer....

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... Had to change the siteurl and home links in wp_option DB table to  http://localhost:81/projectname/